# What's the name of the game show?

Tags: wordplay

A well-known game show comes up on TV. They have acquired some expensive coats; A winner chosen at random will receive five coats, leaving one which will go to charity.

The host reads out his script. He says: "And here are the prizes! Exquisite coats! We are giving away `___. ____ ___ ____ __ ___` lucky winner, and the other one will go to charity."

Can you work out the name of the show? (also, what words fill the blanks?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT! Maybe a stupid guess, but could it be...

> [Countdown?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_(game_show)) The missing words would be something like "Six. five for (four) free (three) to (two) one", which sounds like a countdown from 6.

Comment: (they're giving away 6 and five go the winner)

Comment: @DestructibleLemon Oh true. Hmmm, I'll try to come up with something better.

Comment: Spot on, you got it!

Comment: I'm also amazed at how quickly you got it, both the missing words and the name of the show.